# Удалить символ переноса строки между тегами html

Tags: linux, shell

Есть фрагмент html-документа.

```html
<td width="504" style="border-top: 1px solid #000000; border-bottom: 1px solid #000000; border-left: 1px solid #000000; border-right: none; padding-top: 0.05cm; padding-bottom: 0.05cm; padding-left: 0.19cm; padding-right: 0cm">
<p><font face="DejaVu Sans, sans-serif"><font size="1" style="font-size: 8pt"><i>тут какой то
текст разделенный
символом переноса строки
</i></font></font>
</p>
<p><font face="DejaVu Sans, sans-serif"><font size="1" style="font-size: 8pt"><i>(тут
тоже тест)</i></font></font></p>
</td>
```

Необходимо, используя shell убрать переносы строки только там, где есть текст между тегами i и /i.  Результат должен быть таким

```html
<td width="504" style="border-top: 1px solid #000000; border-bottom: 1px solid #000000; border-left: 1px solid #000000; border-right: none; padding-top: 0.05cm; padding-bottom: 0.05cm; padding-left: 0.19cm; padding-right: 0cm">
<p><font face="DejaVu Sans, sans-serif"><font size="1" style="font-size: 8pt"><i>тут какой то текст разделенный символом переноса строки
</i></font></font>
</p>
<p><font face="DejaVu Sans, sans-serif"><font size="1" style="font-size: 8pt"><i>(тут тоже тест)</i></font></font></p>
</td>
```

Comment: `<img alt="тут какой-то\n текст">` Это тоже должно обрабатываться? Или только внутри тега `p`? А если внутри `p` лежит `span`? Вобщем, нужен критерий выбора текста.

Comment: @ kff Поправил вопрос

Comment: @Sebefour Все таки совершенно не понятно что требуется, вы бы привели этот же html, что вверху с уже убранными переносами строки. У вас в начале между `<i> </i>` есть текст а во втором примере его уже нет. И один пробел считается текстом ?

Comment: @Mike Поправил вопрос.

Comment: @Sebefour А однострочник (т.е. весь код в командной строке) на `perl` под понятие `unix shell` подходит ? perl практически на всех системах стоит, ну кроме всяких мелких железок конечно. Просто регулярочка довольно веселая выходит, что то я пока сомневаюсь, что sed справится

Comment: @Mike Да, можно на перле

Comment: @Sebefour Я не понял, что делать если внутри тега <i> есть еще другие теги. Если надо их учитывать, т.е. продолжать убирать переводы кареток, то в принципе можно ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
cat test.html | perl -e '$/="";$_=<>;s/(<i>|(?!^)\G)[^\n<]*\K\n(?=.*<)/ /gs;print;' >newfile.html
```

Заменяет переводы кареток на пробелы, от `<i>` до открытия другого тега (т.е. до `<`)

Answer (score 0):

Проще всего обработать эти данные скриптом на PHP, поскольку в PHP есть удобная функция [str_split](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.str-split.php). Алгоритм следующий:

1. Загружаем весь код страницы в строку.
2. Удаляем все переносы строк между тегами, то есть все строки вида `">\n<"`, `">\n\n<"`, `">\n\n\n<"` и т.д. заменяем на подстроку `"><"`, увеличивая число символов переноса строки до какого-нибудь максимального значения, выбранного теоретически.
3. Вырезаем код скриптов используя подстроки `<script` и `</script>`. В результате остаётся код, разделённый на несколько строк, в которых символ переноса строки встречается только в "тексте", а также строки, содержащие код скриптов.
4. Удаляем символы переноса из строк, содержащих текст.
5. Склеиваем код страницы обратно в одну строку, добавляя к коду скриптов вырезанные теги `<script` и `</script>`.
6. Сохраняем результат в файл.

Comment: Спасибо. Но решение не будет универсальным. и я не могу использовать PHP